# Change content in div based on button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I created several h2 tags and situated them into a list, they all are clickable and when clicked they reveal content in a div that. This is great and all, but I want the previous content to disappear and be replaced by the new content.

Here's what the buttons look like;

```
    <div id="h2List">      
        <h2 id="reveal1">Who are the main characters?</h2>

        <h2 id="reveal2">The action takes place on</h2>

        <h2 id="reveal3">Space crafts include</h2>

        <h2 id="reveal4">What are those things??</h2>

        <h2 id="reveal5">When they're not flying their driving</h2>
    </div>
```

This is the div holding the content;

```
    <div id="h2Reveal">
                <ul class="hidden" id="listOfCharacters">
                </ul>
                <ul class="hidden" id="listOfPlanets">
                </ul>
                <ul class="hidden" id="spaceStuff">
                </ul>
                <ul class="hidden" id="things">
                </ul>
                <ul class="hidden" id="drive">
                </ul>
            </div>
```

and finally this is the jQuery i'm using to toggle the info lists in the second div;

```
    $("#reveal1").on("click", function () {
            $("#listOfCharacters").toggle();
        }
    );

    $("#reveal2").on("click", function () {
            $("#listOfPlanets").toggle();
        }
    );
    $("#reveal3").on("click", function () {
            $("#spaceStuff").toggle();
        }
    );
    $("#reveal4").on("click", function () {
            $("#things").toggle();
        }
    );
    $("#reveal5").on("click", function () {
            $("#drive").toggle();
        }
    );
```

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use toggleClass

```
$("#reveal1").on("click", function () {
            $("#listOfCharacters").toggleClass('hidden');
        }
    );

    $("#reveal2").on("click", function () {
            $("#listOfPlanets").toggleClass('hidden');
        }
    );
    $("#reveal3").on("click", function () {
            $("#spaceStuff").toggleClass('hidden');
        }
    );
    $("#reveal4").on("click", function () {
            $("#things").toggleClass('hidden');
        }
    );
    $("#reveal5").on("click", function () {
            $("#drive").toggleClass('hidden');
        }
    );
```

Comment: This does work but it seems like it does the same as my code. which is reveal the list associated with the h2 tag when clicked and also hide the associated list when clicked a second time. What I am trying to do would be like when reveal 1 is clicked it displays the list associated with it. Then say the person clicks on reveal 5, I want to hide the list that was previously displayed and replace it with the one associated to reveal 5. I implemented both suggested code blocks and they both work but they did the same as what I originally had coded.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with using `toggleClass`, but you can tighten it up a bit and improve maintainability by introducing a mapping from the source id to the target.

```
var mapping = {
    "reveal1": "#listOfCharacters",
    "reveal2": "#listOfPlanets",
    "reveal3": "#spaceStuff",
    "reveal4": "#things",
    "reveal5": "#drive"
};

$("h2").on("click", function(event) {
    $(mapping[event.target.id]).toggleClass('hidden');
});
```